# Conjecture on minimum size of graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, extremal-graph-theory, formal-proof

Given a graph $G(V,E)$, let $\chi(G)$ be its chromatic number, and $\chi_1(G)$ its 1-improper chromatic number (meaning that each node can have at most 1 neighbor with the same color; or another way of looking at this is that you are allowed to remove any matching from $G$).

It is fairly easy to prove that a graph that satisfies $\chi_1=\chi$ has at least $2\chi-1$ vertices (a proof by induction exists).

However, determining the minimum number of edges in order for the equality to hold seems more difficult.

Quick drawings suggest the number of edges must be at least $2(\chi-1)^2$, but I cannot manage to prove it. Any suggestions?

Note: it is easy to see that the number of edges must be larger than $\chi(\chi-1)$. Indeed, extremal theory tells us the number of edges in a graph is always larger than (or equals) $\chi(\chi-1)/2$, but if we can remove any matching, it has to be larger than  (or equal to) $\chi(\chi-1)$.

---

Here is a possible MIP formulation for the 1-improper chromatic number $\chi_1(G)$:

#### Variables

- $y_c \in \{0,1\}$, takes value $1$ if color $c\in K=\{1,...,n\}$ is used
- $x_{vc}\in \{0,1\}$, takes value $1$ if color $c \in K$ is assigned to node $v \in V$
- $\delta_{uv}\in \{0,1\}$, takes value $1$ if vertices $u$ and $v$ share the same color, $(u,v)\in E$

#### Objective Function

$$
\min \; \sum_{c \in K} y_c
$$

#### Constraints

- One color per node:
  $$
  \sum_{c \in K} x_{vc} = 1 \quad \forall v \in V
  $$
- If vertex $v$ takes color $c$, $y_c$ is activated:
  $$
  x_{vc} \le y_c \quad \forall v \in V, \forall c \in K
  $$
- If endpoints of an edge $(u,v)$ share the same color, $\delta_{uv}$ is activated:
  $$
  x_{uc}+x_{vc} \le 1 + \delta_{uv}\quad \forall (u,v) \in E, \forall c \in K
  $$
- At most one conflict per node:
  $$
  \sum_{u| (u,v)\in E} \delta_{uv} \le 1 \quad \forall v \in V
  $$

---

Using data from [findstat.org](https://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St001716), here is a compilation of results for a few graphs. The conjecture holds for all of the graphs for which the data is available on findstat.org.

[image]

---

**Disclaimer**: This question has been posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448210/conjecture-on-minimum-size-of-a-graph) (math.stackexchange)  5 years ago, and has not been answered, so I am trying another community.

However, someone attempted to make a proof, and although the proof is not correct, it may inspire.

Comment: (with example "$K_{2\chi -1}$ without $\chi-1$ disjoint edges")

Comment: Yes indeed, by larger I meant at least, I have udpated. Thanks for noting.

Comment: slightly off topic: do you have (possibly naive) code to compute the 1-improper chromatic number?  It would be nice to add it to https://findstat.org!

Comment: I do not, but I think it would be quite easy to add a MIP formulation if that would help.

Comment: If you have the time to work out a mip formulation, it should be trivial to translate this into sage code.

Comment: @MartinRubey I have edited to include the MIP formulation. I am not familiar with sage though.

Comment: @Kuifje I have added the statistic to findstat, you can preview it here: https://www.findstat.org/PendingStatistics. It would be great if you could check a few values!

Comment: @MartinRubey Thanks for that, this is very interesting! I will take a look. I wasn't aware of FindStat and I like the concept, great work. May I ask: 1/ what solver is used behind the curtains in FindStat ? 2/ What is the best way to visualize the stats ? The values section ? Is there any form of agregation of the results ?

Comment: @Kuifje FindStat itself doesn't do any computation of statistics.  The values have to be computed elsewhere, and copied into the submission form.  They are just stored in an ordinary database, similar to the http://oeis.org.  However, we entertain ties with sage.  In particular, we try to have sage code whenever possible.  Except for the display of the graph (when you point on it with the mouse) there is no additional visualisation of the values built in.  Once the statistic is reviewed, the first few generating functions are displayed.  So, please let me know whether the values look right!

Comment: @MartinRubey Thanks for the additional info. At first sight, the values look right. I will analyze and compare with the stats of the chromatic number and post it here.

Comment: @MartinRubey I have updated the post with some results from the data available on findstats.org. The conjecture holds for the graphs in findstats.

Comment: The statistic is now https://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St001716.  One further possibly interesting bit of information: apparently, the number of edges in any graph is at least $2(\chi_1-1)^2$, and equality is attained for graphs obtained from a complete graph on $2n+1$ vertices by removing $n$ independent edges.  These have chromatic and improper chromatic number $n+1$.

Comment: Yes indeed ! This is precisely the graph that was sketched which gave birth to the conjecture.

Comment: @MartinRubey I have noticed that there are $1200$ graphs for which $\chi_1$ is given, but only $208$ for $\chi$ (and btw $578$ for $m$). Do you think it would be possible to update the data base in order to have access to $\chi$ (and $m$) for all $1200$ graphs ? Of course the chromatic number can be computed by changing the right hand term of the last constraint to $0$.

Comment: Denote the minimal number of edges by $f(\chi)$. Then for any $\chi-1$ color classes in the minimal example we need at least $f(\chi-1)$ edges, so the number of edges from the last class to other classes is at most $f(\chi)-f(\chi-1)$. Thus twice the number of edges equals $2f(\chi)\leqslant \chi(f(\chi)-f(\chi-1))$, $f(\chi)(\chi-2)\geqslant \chi f(\chi-1)$. This gives some recursive bound, especially if you manage to find small values of $f$. In particular, it gives that $f(\chi)/(\chi(\chi-1))$ is not-decreasing sequence, so $f(\chi)\ge C\chi(\chi-1)$ for $C=f(k)/(k(k-1))$ if $k\le \chi$.

Comment: @Kuifje I guess it would make more sense to use sage directly, you can try https://cocalc.com/ if you do not want to install it on your computer.  I updated the chromatic number anyway.  Let me know (per email) if you need code.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks for your input. I am not sure I follow. In particular, what is $\chi(f(\chi)-f(\chi-1))$ ? The part inside $\chi()$ should be a graph, but $f(\chi)-f(\chi-1)$ is an integer.. (?) Please feel free to elaborate.

Comment: here $\chi$ is an integer, not a function, denote in by $n$ everywhere if you prefer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We prove that, indeed, whenever graph $G=(V,E)$ is $n$-colorable and has less than $2(n-1)^2$ edges, it has 1-improper $(n-1)$-coloring.

Induction by $n$, base $n=1$, $n=2$ is clear. So we assume that $n>2$ and the claim is proved for all smaller values of $n$, but does not hold for our $G$.

Consider the $n$-coloring, denote the colors $1,\ldots,n$, corresponding color classes $C_1,\ldots,C_n$, so $V=\sqcup C_i$. For disjoint subsets $V_1,V_2\subset V$ we denote by $E(V_1,V_2)$ the set of edges between $V_1$ and $V_2$ and by $e(V_1,V_2):=|E(V_1,V_2)|$ the number of such edges. We also relax these notations to $E(v,V_2)$ if $V_1=\{v\}$, and so on.

Note that if $E(C_i,C_j)$ for some $i\ne j$ does not contain two edges with common endpoint, we may construct a 1-improper coloring just by uniting colors $i$ and $j$. So this is not the case, in particular $e(C_i,C_j)\geqslant 2$. We start with

**Lemma.** $e(C_i,V\setminus C_i)\leqslant 4n-7$ for every $i=1,\ldots,n$.

**Proof.** Assume the contrary: $e(C_i,V\setminus C_i)\geqslant 4n-6$. Then the graph induced on $V\setminus C_i$ has less then $2(n-1)^2-(4n-6)=2(n-2)^2$ edges. By induction proposition it has a 1-improper $(n-2)$-coloring. Add $C_i$ colored with $(n-1)$-st color, and get a 1-improper $(n-1)$-coloring of $G$. A contradiction.

Consider several cases.

1. $e(C_i,C_j)=2$ for some $i\ne j$. Say, $i=1$, $j=2$, $E(C_1,C_2)=\{ac,bc\}$ for $a,b\in C_1$, $c\in C_2$. Assume that $e(b,C_i)<2$ for certain $i>2$. Then we may recolor $b$ to color $i$, $C_1\setminus \{b\}$ to color 2 and obtain a 1-improper $(n-1)$-coloring. Thus $e(b,C_i)\geqslant 2$ for all $i>2$, analogously $e(a,C_i)\geqslant 2$. Therefore $e(C_1,C_i)\geqslant 4$, and $e(C_1,V\setminus C_1)\geqslant 2+4(n-2)=4n-6$ that contradicts to Lemma.
2. $e(C_i,C_j)=3$ for some $i\ne j$, but not all 3 edges of $E(C_i,C_j)$ share a common endpoint. Say, $i=1$, $j=2$, $E(C_1,C_2)=\{ac,bc,e\}$, where $a,b\in C_1$, $c\in C_2$, $e$ is not incident to $c$ and to $a$ (but $e$ may be incident to $b$ or not). Assume that $e(c,C_i)<2$ for certain $i>2$. Then recoloring $c$ to $i$, $C_2\setminus \{c\}$ to 1 we get a 1-improper $(n-1)$-coloring of $G$, that is impossible. Analogous recoloring works if $e(b,C_i)<2$. Thus $e(\{b,c\},C_i)\geqslant 4$ for all $i\geqslant 3$. Consider two subcases.

2.1) $e$ is incident to $b$. Then $G\setminus \{b,c\}$ is $(n-1)$-colorable (unite colors 1 and 2 in our coloring of $G$), and has less than $2(n-1)^2-3-4(n-2)<2(n-2)^2$ edges. Thus it has a 1-impoper $(n-2)$-coloring and we may add $\{b,c\}$ with extra color to get a 1-improper $(n-1)$-coloring of $G$.

2.2) $e=uv$, $u\in C_1\setminus \{a,b\}$, $v\in C_2\setminus \{c\}$. Then for every $i>2$ we have $e(a,C_i)\geqslant 1$, $e(u,C_i)\geqslant 1$: otherwise recolor $a$ or $u$, correspondingly, to color $i$, and get a case 1). Totally $e(C_1,C_i)\geqslant 4$, and $e(C_1,V\setminus C_1)\geqslant 3+4(n-2)=4n-5$, that contradicts to Lemma.

3. $e(C_i,C_j)=3$ for certain $i\ne j$ and all edges of $E(C_i,C_j)$ share a common endpoint. Say, $i=1$, $j=2$, $E(C_1,C_2)=\{ad,bd,cd\}$, where $a,b,c\in C_1$, $d\in C_2$. Recolor $C_2\setminus \{d\}$ to color 1. Now $C_2=\{d\}$. Assume that still $e(C_i,C_j)=3$ for certain $i,j$ different from 2. Then the edges from $E(C_i,C_j)$ share a common endpoint (since case 2 is already considered), let this endpoint $v$ belong to $C_j$. Thus we may make $|C_j|=1$ by recoloring $C_j\setminus \{v\}$ to color $i$. Now we have two color classes $2,j$ of size 1 that contradicts to $e(C_2,C_j)\geqslant 2$. Therefore it remains to consider case
4. $e(C_i,C_j)\geqslant 4$ whenever $i\ne j$ and $2\notin \{i,j\}$. Then $|E|=\sum_{i<j} e(C_i,C_j)\geqslant 3(n-1)+4{n-1\choose 2}>2(n-1)^2$, a contradiction.

Comment: I'm still processing your proof, but I like how the cases from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448210/conjecture-on-minimum-size-of-a-graph) re appear. Out of curiosity were you inspired by the other (incomplete) proof, or did you restart from scratch ?

Comment: In case 2.1, how do you count the number of edges in $G\setminus \{b,c\}$?

Comment: I subtract edges incident to $b, c$, there are 3(between $C_1$, $C_2$) plus at least 4 times $(n-2)$: 4 to each other color

Comment: No, I did not read that post ("we are lazy and not curious")

Comment: Shouldn't the Lemma be if $G$ satsifies $\chi= \chi_1$ then $e(C_i,V \setminus C_i) \color{red}{\ge} 4n-7$?

Comment: I think it should be $\leqslant$: if the number of edges between $C_i$ and $V\setminus C_i$ is large then the number od edges in $V\setminus C_i$ is small and we may apply induction hypothesis

Comment: Hmmm yes, I keep getting mixed up :). Thank you Fedor!

Comment: But if $n=2$, and $G=P_3=a-b-c$, $C_1=\{b\}$, $C_2=\{a,c\}$, isn't $e(C_2,V \setminus C_2) = e(C_2,C_1)=2 > 8-7$ ?

Comment: But we assumed the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove that any graph with $\chi_1(G)>n$ has at least $2n^2$ edges (with no assumptions on $\chi(G)$). This provides a sharp estimate (and the method also shows how to construct an optimal graph).

**Lemma.** Assume that the maximal degree in $G$ does not exceed $2k-1$. Then $\chi_1(G)\leq k$.

*Proof.* Consider a coloring in $k$ colors with the smallest number of monocolor edges. Assume that a vertex $v$ has two neighbors of its color $c$; then there is a color $c’$ appearing among the neighbors of $v$ at most once. Recoloring $v$ with $c’$ decreases the number of monocolor edges. This contradiction proves the Lemma.

Back to our statement. Induction on $n$. The base case $n=0$ is trivial. For the step, arguing indirectly, assume that $G$ has less than $2n^2$ edges but $\chi_1(G)>n$. Find a vertex $v_1$ with $d(v_1)\geq 2n$ (otherwise apply the Lemma).

Next, in $G-v_1$ find a vertex $v_2$ of degree at least $2n-2$ (otherwise, color $G-v_1$ in $n-1$ colors $1$-improperly and color $v_1$ with the $n$th color). Then $G-v_1-v_2$ has less than.$2n^2-2n-(2n-2)=2(n-1)^2$ edges, so $\chi_1(G-v_1-v_2)\leq n-1$ by the inductive hypothesis. It remains to color $v_1$ and $v_2$ with the $n$th color to get a $1$-improper coloring of $G$.

**Remark.** In the same manner, one can obtain an estimate for $e(G)$ in terms of $\chi_m(G)$.